# web scraping with a dynamic list

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape out all the breweries listed on the brewers association page (https://www.brewersassociation.org/directories/breweries/) and I have googled a ton and tried multiple ways to get it, but I'm brand new to web scraping and can't figure out it. I am using Beautiful Soup, but if there's something better for this type of page I'll happily switch. Among many failed attempts that have returned errors, I have tried the codes below that at least run.

```
brew_name = soup.find(id='ajax-content').find_all(class_=re.compile('name'))

brew_name = soup.find(id='ajax-content')
```

the first one just returns a blank set and the second returns

```
<div class="with-results" id="ajax-content"><!--Dynamically Filled in--></div>
```

Any help to get me moving in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is not about BeautifulSoup. The website is getting data by different requests made to the server. Monitor the network of the website with chrome developer options and find how to trace them.

Comment: You might have a look at [**`Selenium`**](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Problem is, you're likely getting the page before any `ajax` have been loaded (that is, a button has been clicked, a pagedown menu has been changed, etc.). You're simply getting the bare bone html skeleton before the real data comes in.

Comment: ah that's a good point. If i wanted to select the "microbreweries" checkbox would I do something like `soup.find(id='micro').click()`?